# Onnx 'helper' and 'checker' attribute are not defined

Tags: deep-learning, protocol-buffers, caffe2, onnx

I have onnx 0.2.1 installed on my conda virtual environment

```
conda list | grep onnx

packages in environment at /Users/aanirud/anaconda2/envs/onnx:
onnx 0.2.1 py27_1 ezyang
onnx-caffe2 0.2.1 py27hbe716ef_1 ezyang
onnx-mxnet 0.4.1
```

But I am not able to use the onnx.checker or onnx.helper attributes. When I try to use them I get the following error -

```
import onnx
onnx.checker.check_model("toy_model.onnx")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'checker'
```

Get the same error when I try to use onnx.helper. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the onnx version, there was a bug in the old version. Using onnx >= 1.0.0 works

Running the following works -
git clone --recursive https://github.com/onnx/onnx.git
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 CC=clang CXX=clang++ python setup.py install